# Magento 2.4 : Issue with Initializing 3rd party JS library : Leaflet.js

Tags: magento2.4

I am trying to include a map in checkout page using Leaflet.js . For that I included Leaflet.js reference in checkout_index_index.xml like following.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Iwdat_AddressExt25::css/custom.css"/> 
        <css src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" src_type="url"/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Iwdat_AddressExt25::jsloader.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Having that I am getting following error in browser console.

[image]

---

Earlier I tried to load Leaflet.js via requirejs with following , no error but leaflet.js wasnt initialized in that case. Therefore I tried the aforementioned inclusion via layout xml.

Having leaflet.js copied to local server.

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/billing-address/details.html':
            'Iwdat_AddressExt25/web/template/billing-address/details.html',
            'leaflet':'Iwdat_AddressExt25::js/leaflet.js'                        
        }
    },
    deps: ['Iwdat_AddressExt25/js/custom','Iwdat_AddressExt25/js/iwdatcustom_customer']
};
```

Can someone please guide me to resolve this and get leaflet.js initialized in checkout page properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve it with declare leaflet as a dependancy in requirejs-config.js .

```
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/billing-address/details.html':
            'Iwdat_AddressExt85/web/template/billing-address/details.html'            
        }
    },
    deps: ['Iwdat_AddressExt85/js/custom','Iwdat_AddressExt85/js/iwdatcustom_customer','Iwdat_AddressExt85/js/leaflet']

};
```

I did copy leaflet js file, css file and its resources to my custom magento module.

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil